# Вы(,) как специалист(,) что скажете?

Tags: пунктуация

"Вы как специалист что скажете" - Нужна ли запятая перед как и специалист. Вроде бы как в значении "в качестве", а вроде бы можно сказать "будучи специалистом". Подскажите.Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны, но смысловые оттенки разные.

1) Вы, как специалист (по это теме), что скажете? Значение причины: выскажитесь, так как это ваша специальность.

2) Вы как специалист что скажете? Значение в качестве. Обсуждаются разные аспекты проблемы, вы можете высказать свое мнение и как обычный пользователь,  и как специалист.

Comment: Ещё можно слово "специалист" превратить в обращение к незнакомцу: "Вы как, специалист, - что скажете?" :)

Comment: Vera права по сути, но мне кажется, что значение причины с этим вопросительным предложением не вяжется, по крайней мере, если нет восклицательного оттенка.